# How can I list the Kafka consumer lag and latest offset per partition and consumer group using the Kafka .NET client API?

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I'm trying to get the consumer lag using the .NET Confluent.Kafka 1.4.0-RC1 (for Net472). 
I can get the desired result using this script:

```
$ bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group Grp1 --describe
```

Resulting:

```
GROUP           TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                  HOST            CLIENT-ID
Grp1            test3           1          15              15              0               rdkafka-ca76855f-7b66-4bf1-82bc-73e9a1c1cf71 /10.186.129.93  rdkafka
Grp1            test3           2          13              13              0               rdkafka-d64379dc-881a-4f6f-a793-51e832cc2f5a /10.186.129.93  rdkafka
Grp1            test3           0          9               9               0               rdkafka-a25bdb80-3b70-4e42-963e-d41ad9e2a99a /10.186.129.93  rdkafka
Grp1            test            0          68              68              0               -                                            -               -
```

I'm not able to get similar report using the .NET client code. Here's the code I've been trying - but getting nothing as the `consumer.Assignment` property has an empty collection.

```
private string WriteConsumerGroupLags(string bootstrapServers, string consumerGroupName) {
    // kafka-console-consumer.bat --zookeeper MW45670117:2380 --topic powertelemetry --consumer-property group.id=test123 --consumer-property enable.auto.commit=true

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("\n");
    sb.AppendLine("Consumer Group Lag Report");
    sb.AppendLine("-------------------------");
    ConsumerConfig config = new ConsumerConfig {
        BootstrapServers = bootstrapServers,
        GroupId = consumerGroupName,
        AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest
    };

    using (var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(config).Build()) {
        foreach (TopicPartition tp in consumer.Assignment) {
            string topic = tp.Topic;
            int partitionID = tp.Partition.Value;
            // gets the current position (offset) for the specific topic/partition
            Offset offset = consumer.Position(new TopicPartition(topic, new Partition(partitionID)));
            sb.AppendLine($"Offset value is: {offset.Value}");

            // returns current commited offset for the current assignment
            List<TopicPartitionOffset> tpos = consumer.Committed(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));
            foreach (TopicPartitionOffset tpo in tpos) {
                sb.AppendLine($"Commited offset for partition {tpo.TopicPartition} is {tpo.Offset}");
            }
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Looking for both consumer lag and latest offset per partition/consumer-group.

Comment: I suggest setting up external tools that can monitor lag for all consumers in all languages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I finally found how to do it. Looks like you need to set the topic partitions assignments to the consumer group. In my case the topic was `test3` and I had 3 partitions to it. This had to be set in the code. I guess a more generic implementation would be to pass into this method the List associated with this group. 
Here is how I get the consumer lag:

```
private string WriteConsumerGroupLags(string bootstrapServers, string consumerGroupName) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("\n");
    sb.AppendLine("Consumer Group Lag Report");
    sb.AppendLine("-------------------------");
    ConsumerConfig config = new ConsumerConfig {
        BootstrapServers = bootstrapServers,
        GroupId = consumerGroupName,
        AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest
    };

    using (var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(config).Build()) {
        List<TopicPartition> topic_partitions = new List<TopicPartition>() {
            { new TopicPartition("test3", new Partition(0)) },
            { new TopicPartition("test3", new Partition(1) ) },
            { new TopicPartition("test3", new Partition(2) ) } };

        consumer.Assign(topic_partitions);

        List<TopicPartitionOffset> tpos = consumer.Committed(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40));
        foreach (TopicPartitionOffset tpo in tpos) {
            WatermarkOffsets w = consumer.QueryWatermarkOffsets(tpo.TopicPartition, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40));
            long commited = tpo.Offset.Value;
            long log_end_offset = w.High.Value;
            long lag = log_end_offset - commited;
            sb.AppendLine($"Commited offset for Topic {tpo.TopicPartition.Topic} Partition {tpo.TopicPartition.Partition} is {commited} out of Wantermark end offset {log_end_offset} Lag is: {lag}");
        }

        sb.AppendLine();
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: did you find how to map topic to consumer groups to generate `topic_partitions`?

Answer (score 1):

I have expanded on your answer to include generating the model for topic partitions.

```
public class Offsets
{
   public string WriteConsumerGroupLags(string bootstrapServers, string consumerGroupName)
   {
      var sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.AppendLine("\n");
      sb.AppendLine("Consumer Group Lag Report");
      sb.AppendLine("-------------------------");

      var config = new ConsumerConfig
      {
         BootstrapServers = bootstrapServers,
         GroupId = consumerGroupName,
         SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.Ssl
      };

      using var adminClient = new AdminClientBuilder(config).Build();
      using var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(config).Build();


      var meta = adminClient.GetMetadata(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));

      var topicPartitions = new List<TopicPartition>();

      foreach (var topicMeta in meta.Topics.Where(x => !x.Topic.Contains("__")))
      {
         topicPartitions.AddRange(topicMeta.Partitions.Select(topicMetaPartition => new TopicPartition(topicMeta.Topic, new Partition(topicMetaPartition.PartitionId))));
      }

      consumer.Assign(topicPartitions);

      List<TopicPartitionOffset> tpos = consumer.Committed(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40));
      foreach (TopicPartitionOffset tpo in tpos)
      {
         WatermarkOffsets w = consumer.QueryWatermarkOffsets(tpo.TopicPartition, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40));
         long commited = tpo.Offset.Value;
         long log_end_offset = w.High.Value;
         long lag = log_end_offset - commited;
         sb.AppendLine(
            $"Commited offset for Topic {tpo.TopicPartition.Topic} Partition {tpo.TopicPartition.Partition} is {commited} out of Wantermark end offset {log_end_offset} Lag is: {lag}");
      }

      sb.AppendLine();

      return sb.ToString();
   }
}
```